# Máximo y Mínimo de un array tridimensional php

Tags: php

**PROBLEMA:**

Necesito sacar solo el valor máximo y el mínimo de cada ciudad de los 12 meses que se han introducido.

Gracias de antemano.

```
$ciudades[$ciudad][$meses]['maxima', 'minima']

$meses=array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", 
             "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
$ciudad=array("Madrid", "Barcelona", "Bilbao", "Sevilla");
```

Comment: No tienes que mostrar todo el código. Muestra un pequeño ejemplo de los arrays y de la parte problemática del código y explícanos con claridad qué es lo que quieres y qué problema tienes. Tal como está ahora la pregunta no se entiende. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla.

Comment: max($ciudades[$ciudad)   [mira](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php)??

Comment: @JackNavaRow  No entiendo lo que dices

Comment: A que uses la funcion `max()` . Yo no logro entender a que max y min te refieres